# Reading class 0 sms in android

Tags: android, sms

My backend service sends a Type 0 sms `(PID 0x40)` to authenticate the android client. My app is suppose to read the sms and authenticate itself with the information. Is there a way to verify the Type 0 sms is being received by the client. I have added logs in the broadcast receiver that logs sms. I can see logs that tells normal sms received,  but nothing for Type 0 sms.

My target device is android 10, and the buildsdk version is 29

Comment: What do you mean by **class 0 sms** ?

Comment: SMS with PID 64. I think they are called Type 0 , not CLass 0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't confuse type zero and class 0. Those are different types of SMS. Type zero isn't saved or seen by user, class 0 of 'flash' sms is.

Having said that, if you are in the US, keep in mind that Type Zero SMS are automatically blocked unless sent by a mobile stations or Telecomm.